# Angular 12: Listening to multiple children events in Parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, eventemitter

I'm a beginner to Angular when It comes to events and such.

Lately I've been working on this project where I have a parent Component called **Layout**, which contains multiple child components that are supposed to do CRUD operations through various **services**.

Now the **Layout** component has a navbar and this navbar shows the number of items I have in my inventory for each category.

**Objective :** When I make an Add or Delete request in one of the children, the parent component is supposed to fire a request to the backend. That way it will retrieve the new number of items from the database

**Problem :** I don't knwo the correct approach I should be using here, I know that I need to listen to the events from each child component, but I didn't know how.

Am I supposed to listen to the components or subscribe to each service and wait for it to emit an event ?

What's the best way to do this ?

My code is quite long so I'll add some fragments to clarify what I'm doing:

**Layout.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.prepareNavbar()
    }
```

**Layout.component.html**

```
<nav> 
<!-- Here I display the numbers of each item retrieved from the database -->
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**AddItem1.component.ts**

```
addItem(){
this.Categorie1Service.addItem.subscribe()
}
```

**DeleteItem.component.ts**

```
DeleteItem(){
this.Categorie2Service.DeletItem.subscribe()
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the `@Output()` decorator, see this guide: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: Hi, I read the documentation but what I didn't understand is that the examples have the children inside @Component({ template: ...}) while I don't

Comment: Is the `router-outlet` actually relevant here? Where are the items whose events you want to react to? Within the `nav`?

Comment: I thought is was relevant because I didn't have a template, instead the layout.html shows the component used by the router in <router-outlet>, I ended up using a service between my parent and children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using a Shared Data Service

You can share a dataService over your application, which you have figured out already. Which is a good choice if you want to use the shared data in other places of your application.

#### Using onActivate

In child.component.ts:

```js
@Output() deleteEvent = new EventEmitter
@Output() addEvent = new EventEmitter

deleteItem(id){
    this.deleteEvent.emit(id)
}
addItem(data) {
    this.deleteEvent.emit(data)
}
```

In the parent template:

```html
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

In parent.component.ts:

```js
onActivate(componentReference) {
   componentReference.deleteEvent.subscribe((id) => {
      // implementation
   });
   
   componentReference.addEvent.subscribe((data) => {
      // implementation 
   })
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where I should put the <app-child> tag, my parent component has a dozen child components already

Comment: Problem is, you can't put `(someEvent)` on the `router-outlet`, it would need to go on the components that are added in its place as a result of routing.

Comment: I understand, I did some research and it turned out that (someEvent) is not applicable in my case. I ended up creating a service with a behaviousSubject and a method emitting it, after that I called the method from my components and it worked.